# Buscador del header cambie su funcion segun componentes renderizado

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

estoy desarrollando un página web con reactjs y tengo un header y footer que siempre estan renderizandose mientras que va cambiando solo el main que son otros componentes, usando react-router-dom.
En mi header tengo un buscador y quiero darle una funcion diferentes segun el elemento que este renderizando, por ejemplo si esta cargado el componentes home.js se ejecuta x funcion en el header.js y si esta cargado, mi perfil, el buscador del header ejecute otra funcion.
Espero poder explicarme

asi tengo mi router

```
function App() {
  
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Header />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/Favorites" element={<Favorites />}/>
    </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hola, no se si sabes que es redux, pero es la mejor opción. Trata de centralizar el estado de las variables en un único sitio, y  modifica la variable de estado dependiendo donde este el usuario, de esta forma podrás hacer lo que planteas.

Comment: alguna referencia para ver?

Comment: https://react-redux.js.org/

Comment: redux es una forma de resolverlo, también puedes usar una variable state en tu App.js y tener un handle que se ejecute al hacer el trigger que cambiará la ruta, luego esta variable la puedes pasar como un prop a tu componente header.

Answer (score 0):

Con ayuda de comentarios, lo que hice fue importar el header en las páginas Home y Favorites, y darle una prop de buscador, cada pages le dara el mismo nombre de prop pero una funcion diferente, y funcion

en Home.js

```
return(
<>
<Header
buscador={inputSearch} //y en favorites.js darle a buscador otra funcion
/>
...
</>
```